# multiple select query

Tags: arrays, oracle11g

I want to combine the data from a table and from a pipelined table function into a single `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  My pipelined table function returns an array of strings

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name
  RETURN string_type
  PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  PIPE ROW(pr_package.constant1);
  PIPE ROW(pr_package.constant2);
  RETURN;
END;
```

I tried to write the query using a scalar subquery

```
open cur_TEMP for
  Select AR.*,(select * from table(FUNCTION)) from TABLE1 AR
```

but that throws an error "single-row subquery returns more than one row".

Comment: STOP SHOUTING, YOU'RE HURTING MY EYES !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

```
select * 
  from table(FUNCTION)
```

returns multiple rows, you cannot use it in a scalar subquery.  You could do a Cartesian product between the output of the pipelined table function and the table

```
OPEN cur_temp
 FOR SELECT ar.*, f.column_value
       FROM table1 ar 
            CROSS JOIN table(function) f;
```

but it is quite rare that you would intentionally want to generate a Cartesian product.  If the table has N rows and the pipelined table function returns M rows, the query I posted will return N * M rows which gets rather large rather quickly.  If that's not what you want, please explain the desired output in a bit more detail.

Comment: This is somewhat right answer but it repeats the rows of first result table for how many values returns in function as you say but i dont want these repeated rows

Comment: @user1227771 - Then what, exactly, do you want?  If the pipelined table function returns multiple rows, how do you know which row from the table you want to match to which row of the pipelined table function?  Or, perhaps, you want to have two (or more) additional columns added to the result set, one for each row returned by the pipelined table function?  Or something else?